# Use different databases embedded in Neo4j with Java

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-embedded

I am trying to evaluate different datamodels in Neo4j. For that reason I have created two databases which have those different models and saved them in the same directory:

```
path/to/database/graphModel1
path/to/database/graphModel2
```

The next step is that I have created an application with java where I can select the datamodel and the query I want to evaluate (there are only a few predefined queries). Depending which model was selected I want to use the instance of the embedded database. At the moment I use the following if-clause to distinguish between them:

```
if (model.equals("G1")) {
    graph = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH_1);
} else if (model.equals("G2")) {
    graph = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH_2);
} 
registerShutdownHook(graph);
```

But using that snippet of code I got the following exception after I did the first query with model1 and want to compute the same query with model2:

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter@1f1e9b8' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:330)
... 69 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Unable to obtain lock on store lock file: path/to/database/graphModel1/store_lock. Please ensure no other process is using this database, and that the directory is writable (required even for read-only access)
at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:78)
at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.start(StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.java:44)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507)
... 71 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't lock lock file path/to/database/graphModel1/lock because another process already holds the lock.
at org.neo4j.io.fs.FileLock.getLockFileBasedFileLock(FileLock.java:126)
at org.neo4j.io.fs.FileLock.getOsSpecificFileLock(FileLock.java:70)
at org.neo4j.io.fs.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.tryLock(DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.java:85)
at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:74)
... 73 more
```

I realized that there are already a `store_lock` and a `lock` on the first database but how does this affect starting a second embedded database? Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your GraphDatabase instance was not properly shut down - leaving it in a locked state. I see in your code above that you are registering a shutdown hook, but for `graphDB` not `graph`. This might explain how the instance was not properly shut down.

If you know there are no other instances pointing to your Neo4j directory you can try manually deleting the `graph.db/lock` and `graph.db/store_lock` files and running your code again.

Comment: I am sorry, the difference between `graphDB` and `graph` were caused by a lack of concentration. The shutdown hook is registered for `graph`. As I shutdown the database manually I cannot create a new one, I have already tried this approach.

Answer (score 0):

There's long term common misunderstanding in the directory structure for (embedded) database storage location. Designers submit "root" DB folder in the API while required to submit child repository folder.

```
new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( "path/to/db" ) // wrong
new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( "path/to/db/repository" ) // correct
```

For described case, consider to extend paths to created/reused database locations, by "repository" folder (this name could be varied):

```
path/to/database/graphModel1/repository
path/to/database/graphModel2/repository
```

When both DB instances start simultaneously, you will see next file system items created:

```
path/to/database/graphModel1/repository
path/to/database/graphModel1/logs
path/to/database/graphModel1/store_lock

path/to/database/graphModel2/repository
path/to/database/graphModel2/logs
path/to/database/graphModel2/store_lock
```

As one can see, there are no any "store_lock" conflicts there. Verified with Neo4j version 3.5.17, "embedded" setup.